# Remove data from database but not from datagrid. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have problem with refreshing my datagrid. 
Have simple application to create new clients connected with Entity Framework. 
Have 3 buttons to create new one, save changes and delete. First two are working well, but have little problem with delete selected row.
After click delete button, object is removed from database but datagrid is not update.
I tried to use .Items.Resfresh(), load ItemSource from the beggining, remove selected row but there are catched some exceptions

f.e. (Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.)

Should I implement ObservableCollection (i'm quite new to wpf, if yes then how)?

**C#**

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _isLoading = true;
    clientDataGrid.ItemsSource = _repo.ClientsListInMemory();
    _clientViewSource = (ObjectDataProvider)FindResource("clientViewSource");
    _isLoading = false;
    clientDataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void deleteBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HotelContext db = new HotelContext();
    Client client = clientDataGrid.SelectedItem as Client;
    try
    {
        _currentClient = db.Clients.Where(c => c.Id == client.Id).Single();
        db.Clients.Remove(_currentClient);
        db.SaveChanges();
    //  refreshFunction()?
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="clientViewSource"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="clientDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource clientViewSource}}" Margin="0,10,323,0" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" SelectionChanged="clientDataGrid_SelectionChanged" SelectedValuePath="Id" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="firstNameColumn" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lastNameColumn" Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="phoneNumberColumn" Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Header="Phone Number" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You can manually remove it from underlying collection. `((List<Client>)clientDataGrid.ItemsSource).Remove(_currentClient);`

Answer (score 0):

You might refresh source of your DataGrid after deletion of your item.

What you might apply here is next:

```
private void deleteBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HotelContext db = new HotelContext();
    Client client = clientDataGrid.SelectedItem as Client;
    try
    {
        _currentClient = db.Clients.Where(c => c.Id == client.Id).Single();
        db.Clients.Remove(_currentClient);
        db.SaveChanges();
        clientDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
        clientDataGrid.ItemsSource = GETYOURCLIENTSFROMDATABASE();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

As you can see I added:

```
clientDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
clientDataGrid.ItemsSource = GETYOURCLIENTSFROMDATABASE();
```

This means, reset your grid source andd insted of GETYOURCLIENTSFROMDATABASE you could write your method which will get current data from database, you could use LINQ or Stored procedures or whateverr you want, and that will simply refresh your UI(Grid).

But in general what I would like to recommend to you is to use INotifyPropertyChanged Interface which will keep your grid updated in a real time, that means if you change a value in a datagrid for example if you delete it item will be removed from a datagrid and so on.. It is easy to implement and that's what you should explore.

But for now, soution I gave you should work.